# Incorrectly encoded message about editing deleted post

Tags: bug, edits, localization, deleted-posts, encoding

An attempt to edit a deleted post by a direct link (when you don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts, or you're an owner of deleted post), e.g., [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/300346/edit) gives a raw text page stated:

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

Meanwhile, if you do the same on a non-English site, you will get wrongly encoded text, e.g., [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1552080/edit):

> РЎРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёРµ СѓРґР°Р»РµРЅРѕ, СЂРµРґР°РєС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёРµ РЅРµРІРѕР·РјРѕР¶РЅРѕ.

The actual translation on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) can be obtained in [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6833).

Comment: The actual bug is  different, which is the fact text is showing instead of sending status code 404, like all other cases of user trying to reach a page they can't access.

Comment: @ShadowWizard about your edit: did you check the link from my post? Are you able to edit? Because I can't.

Comment: I can edit the one here on MSE, I can't edit on ruSO. So the first link you posted does not show me the text "This post is deleted and cannot be edited" but rather taking me to the edit page, so at first I was confused. To see the text i.e. reproduce the bug when one has high rep, they need to open the link when not logged in, or with low rep sock.

Comment: @ShadowWizard interesting, could you please find your own deleted post here and check? It seems that it depends who is the post owner, since I have the same privileges as you have here on MSE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard on attempt to edit from post itself I got the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqelP.png).

Comment: OK, but how is this related to this bug report? It's two different things, and the error you got is not a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard not related, but I didn't realize before that own deleted posts are handled differently in this case. So, yes, your edit is correct, but doesn't cover the case with own deleted post even if the owner has a privilege to see deleted posts.